# SQL server stored procedure cascade insert three tables

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-express, cascade, scope-identity, multiple-records

I am running on my own project. Earlier I was using MS access database but now its not enough to handle such a huge data.

My problem is I am using stored procedures and I need some advice.

I try cascade insert for 3 tables. first table only keeps agreement numbers, second table addresses for agreement and last table stuff for those addresses. single agreement can have many addresses and all those addresses can have many stuff.

Scope_identity,output etc. works well but when i have only single record for all tables.

I hope I could explain system. Simple help would be nice. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table with the fields that you want returned from your insert statement and add the OUTPUT and INTO options into it.

You will also wrap your 3 insert statements in a transaction.

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2183/using-insert-output-in-a-sql-server-transaction/) is a link with more details.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
     Id int,
     Name varchar(20),
     Email varchar(50))

INSERT INTO Customer (
    Name, Email)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.Email, 
INTO #tmp
SELECT DISTINCT 
     Name, Email
FROM StagingTable
```

Comment: i solved this with a weird and long way. sql server type . datatables to sql server, while loop and etc. worked well. its fast but its weird